# C# - Reflection -Identifying Overloaded constructor

Tags: c#

I need to identify the overloaded constructor to pass the values  using reflection .The Partial code is :

```
            asm=Assembly.Load("RulesLibrary");

            Type t = asm.GetType("RulesLibrary.MedicalInsuranceRules");

            object ActObj = Activator.CreateInstance(t); 

            object[] conparam = new object[2];

            conparam[0] = "RuleID"; // string

            conparam[1] =12; // int

// How to find out the overloaded constructor in Type MedicalInsuranceRules

            ConstructorInfo cinfo = t.GetConstructor();

            cinfo.Invoke(ActObj, conparam);
```

**Suppose the type MedicalInsuranceRules contains overloaded constructors**

```
 public   MedicalInsuranceRules( ){}
 public   MedicalInsuranceRules(string ruleID,int subSection ){}
 public   MedicalInsuranceRules(string ruleID,
                                int subSection,string majorDocID ){}
```

**How can i match the excat contructor during reflection ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Type.GetConstructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h93ya84h.aspx) has an overload where you can specify the types of the constructor arguments e.g.

```
var ciInfo = t.GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(string), typeof(int) });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [GetConstructor overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h93ya84h.aspx) that takes an array of types as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `GetConstructors` method instead of `GetConstructor`, then look at the `Parameters` property of each `ConstructorInfo` obtained in order to search for the ones you want.